# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for email.. got this error when i parsing login data through volley

Tags: java, android, xml, api

when i put my username and password on login page. then i got api response but my dashboard activity not open. i am getting W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for email error on my api parameter. when i remove email parameter then this error jump to next parameter. what can i do
? need some help

I am tried many time to login , this api response are working  but activity is not open.

LoginModel.java

```
package com.tsa.nccapp.models;

/**
 * Created by hp on 31-Dec-2018.
 */

public class LoginModel {
    private String regiment_number;
    private String rank;
    private String name_of_cadet;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
    private String father_name;
    private String exam_type;
    private String unit;
    private String ncc_group;
    private String state;
    private String district;
    private String town;
    private String directorate;
    private String membership_status;
    private String username;
    private String password;


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



    public String getName_of_cadet() {
        return name_of_cadet;
    }

    public void setName_of_cadet(String name_of_cadet) {
        this.name_of_cadet = name_of_cadet;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getFather_name() {
        return father_name;
    }

    public void setFather_name(String father_name) {
        this.father_name = father_name;
    }

    public String getExam_type() {
        return exam_type;
    }

    public void setExam_type(String exam_type) {
        this.exam_type = exam_type;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String getNcc_group() {
        return ncc_group;
    }

    public void setNcc_group(String ncc_group) {
        this.ncc_group = ncc_group;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public String getTown() {
        return town;
    }

    public void setTown(String town) {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public String getDirectorate() {
        return directorate;
    }

    public void setDirectorate(String directorate) {
        this.directorate = directorate;
    }


    public String getRegiment_number() {
        return regiment_number;
    }

    public void setRegiment_number(String regiment_number) {
        this.regiment_number = regiment_number;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(String rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.tsa.nccapp;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.tsa.nccapp.Network.NetworkCheck;
import com.tsa.nccapp.custom.CustomActivity;
import com.tsa.nccapp.custom.RightDrawableOnTouchListener;
import com.tsa.nccapp.models.LoginModel;
import com.tsa.nccapp.models.UserModel;
import com.tsa.nccapp.utils.GLOBAL;
import com.tsa.nccapp.validation.Validation;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

/********************************************************
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password. *
 ********************************************************/
public class LoginActivity2 extends CustomActivity {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static  Context context;

    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;

    private boolean pwdFlag = false;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    LinearLayout mainRoot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);
        context = LoginActivity2.this;

        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        init();
    }

    /////////////////////////
    private void init() {
        username = findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mainRoot=findViewById(R.id.main_root);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (NetworkCheck.checkInternet(mainRoot,context))
                    signIn();
            }
        });

        password.setOnTouchListener(new RightDrawableOnTouchListener(password) {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrawableTouch(final MotionEvent event) {
                return onClickSearch(event);
            }

        });
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////
    public void goToDashboard(View view) {
        if (checkValidation()) {
            if (NetworkCheck.checkInternet(mainRoot,context)) {
                login(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    public void goRegistration(View view) {
        if (NetworkCheck.checkInternet(mainRoot,context)) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity2.this, Signup_oneActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void login(final String username, final String password) {
        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity2.this);
        progress.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,  GLOBAL.baseURL+ "loginUser.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        Log.d("Login", s.toString());

                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);

                            if (json.getString("status").equals("0")) {

                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel = new LoginModel();
//                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setName_of_cadet(json.getString("name_of_cadet"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setEmail(json.getString("email"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setMobile(json.getString("mobile"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setRegiment_number(json.getString("regiment_number"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setRank(json.getString("rank"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setFather_name(json.getString("father_name"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setExam_type(json.getString("exam_type"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setUnit(json.getString("unit"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setNcc_group(json.getString("ncc_group"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setState(json.getString("state"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setDistrict(json.getString("district"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setTown(json.getString("town"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setDirectorate(json.getString("directorate"));

                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setUsername(json.getString("username"));
                                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setPassword(json.getString("password"));

                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                                editor.putString("username", username);
                                editor.putString("password", password);
                                editor.commit();
                                GLOBAL.loginType=GLOBAL.USERLOGIN;


                                Log.d("Login", s.toString());
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity2.this, Main2Activity.class));
                                finish();
                            } else {

                                Log.d("Login", s.toString());
                                progress.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            progress.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Some issue in loading" + volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("status", "Login");
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity2.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private boolean onClickSearch(final MotionEvent event) {
        // do something
        pwdFlag = !pwdFlag;
        if (pwdFlag) {
            password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            password.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.off_eye, 0);
        } else {
            password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            password.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.eye_20, 0);
        }
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        return false;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    private boolean checkValidation() {
        boolean ret = true;
        if (!Validation.hasText(password)) ret = false;
        if (!Validation.hasText(username)) ret = false;
        return ret;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////
    public void goHome(View view) {
        if(NetworkCheck.checkInternet(mainRoot,context)) {
            GLOBAL.globalLoginModel = new LoginModel();
            Log.e("json", GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.toString());
            GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setName_of_cadet("Guest User");
            GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setUsername("Guest User");
            /*GLOBAL.loginType=GLOBAL.GUESTLOGIN;*/
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity2.this, Main2Activity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////
//    @Override
//    protected void onStart() {
//        super.onStart();
//        if (NetworkCheck.checkInternet(mainRoot,context)) {
//            GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
//            if (account != null) {
//                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel = new LoginModel();
//                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setUsername(account.getDisplayName());
//                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setName_of_cadet(account.getDisplayName());
//                GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setEmail(account.getEmail());
//                GLOBAL.photoURL = "" + account.getPhotoUrl();
//             /*   GLOBAL.loginType=GLOBAL.GMAILLOGIN;*/
//                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity2.this, Main2Activity.class));
//                finish();
//            }
//        }
//    }

    ///////////////////////////
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//    @Override
//    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
//            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
//            handleSignInResult(task);
//        }
//    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
//        try {
//            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
//            GLOBAL.globalLoginModel = new LoginModel();
//            GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setUsername(account.getDisplayName());
//            GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setName_of_cadet(account.getDisplayName());
//            GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.setEmail(account.getEmail());
//            GLOBAL.photoURL = "" + account.getPhotoUrl();
//            registerWithGPlus();
//        } catch (ApiException e) {
//            Log.w("TAG", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
//        }
    //}

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void goFargotPwd(View view) {
        if (NetworkCheck.checkInternet(mainRoot,context)){
            startActivity(new Intent(context, ForgetPasswordActivity.class));
            finish();}
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//    public void registerWithGPlus() {
//        //Showing the progress dialog
//        final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
//        progress.show();
//        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GLOBAL.baseURL + "social_media_login.php",
//                new Response.Listener<String>() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onResponse(String s) {
//                        try {
//                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
//                            Log.e("j    son", json.toString());
//                            progress.dismiss();
//                          /*  GLOBAL.loginType=GLOBAL.GMAILLOGIN;*/
//                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity2.this, Main2Activity.class));
//                            finish();
//                        } catch (JSONException e) {
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                            progress.dismiss();
//                        }
//                    }
//
//                },
//                new Response.ErrorListener() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
//                        //Showing toast
//                        Toast.makeText(context, "Some issue in loading" + volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        progress.dismiss();
//                    }
//                }) {
//            @Override
//            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
//
//                //Creating parameters
//                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
//
//                //Adding parameters
//                params.put("email", "" + GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.getEmail());
//                params.put("name", "" + GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.getName_of_cadet());
//                params.put("mobile", "" + GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.getMobile());
//                params.put("state", "" + GLOBAL.globalLoginModel.getState());
//                params.put("social_media", "Gmail");
//
//                return params;
//            }
//        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
//        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
//
//        //Adding request to the queue
//        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
//    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Really Exit?")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        LoginActivity2.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }

}
```

Global.java

```
package com.tsa.nccapp.utils;

import com.tsa.nccapp.R;
import com.tsa.nccapp.models.CadetDetailsModels;
import com.tsa.nccapp.models.LoginModel;
import com.tsa.nccapp.models.OtherExamResultModel;
import com.tsa.nccapp.models.PasswordModel;
import com.tsa.nccapp.models.ReportModel;
import com.tsa.nccapp.models.UserModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Created by Akhil Tripathi on 28-12-2017.
 */

public class GLOBAL {
    public final static String baseURL="http://internationalskills.co.in/nccdarpan/API/";

    public static UserModel globalUserModel=null;
    public static LoginModel globalLoginModel=null;
    public static PasswordModel globalPasswordModel=null;


    public static String url="";
    public static String cert="A";

    public static int xD=0;
    public static int yD=0;

    public static final int GMAILLOGIN=2;
    public static final int GUESTLOGIN=1;
    public static final int USERLOGIN=0;

    public static int loginType=USERLOGIN;
    public static String password;
    public static String username;

    public static int textColor= R.color.black;
    public static int BGColor= R.color.light_green;
    public static int textSize= 14;

    public static int scrollAmount=0;
    public static ArrayList<ReportModel> reportModels;

    public static Stack<Integer> lastVisitedIndex=new Stack<>();

    public static String photoURL="https://icons8.com/A.png";

    public static ArrayList<OtherExamResultModel> otherExamResultModels=new ArrayList<>();
    public static CadetDetailsModels cadetFormModel;
}
```

Comment: What does the resulting JSON look like (I see you print it to Log)? Is email present as a JSON parameter in it?

Comment: yes . email is present as a json parameter.

Comment: {
    "status": "0",
    "userData": [
        {
            "regiment_number": "reg001",
            "rank": "rankl009",
            "name_of_cadet": "raman",
            "email": "ramanasht786@gmail.com",
            "mobile": "8130814255",
            "father_name": "Mr. Ramesh",
            "exam_type": "A",
            "unit": "unit1",
            "ncc_group": "gr1",
            "state": "",
            "district": "",
            "town": "",
            "directorate": "dr1",
            "membership_status": "ncc"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Ah ok, well the problem is that the information you want isn't in the root of the JSON object. So, in this case, you will need to get the userData array (something like jsonArr = json.getJSONArray("userData"). Then get the object in that array (is it always just one?), JSONObject innerObject = jsonArr.get(0) for example. THEN finally you can do email = innerObject.getString("email");

Comment: okay sir. i will try to resolve this error.

Comment: Ok, I hope that made sense. If you get stuck, update your question and I will try and provide a more complete answer.

Comment: Thank you so much sir...you save my day. its working.